# Change default gnome-terminal to terminator

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, terminator

Changing default terminal is supposed to be be done with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

[image]
(as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808231/how-do-i-set-default-terminal-to-terminator )

But unfortunately it still not work for every application (like Nemo file browser): the default ugly and limited gnome-terminal is still used.

Comment: "ugly and limited": Please refrain from making such negative and subjective comments. You'd prefer to use Terminator, that's fine, and that's enough information here.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that changing the binary is the only (hard) way to make it works for every app/settings:
(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or right click open terminal, etc.)

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/gnome-terminal /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.bak
sudo ln /usr/bin/terminator /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

Comment: I found out that this symlink gets overwritten after every update: just reapply it.

Comment: Changing symlink is a very bad idea. It may break some applications which direcly uses `gnome-terminal` with some specific options which is available only with `gnome-terminal`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in changing the terminal in Nemo file manager:

Install *dconf Editor*.

Go to `/org/cinnamon/desktop/applications/terminal/exec`.

Turn off '*Use default value*' and enter the command for the terminal you wish to use in '*Custom value*'.